# How to find duplicate substring in a word in a single cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have large data in excel with names in cells like

```
1   THOMASTHOMAS
2   KUMARKUMAR
```

The names in the cells are repeated without spaces or any other delimiter.I want to remove the duplicates from the name in a single cell.

The required output is:

```
1   THOMAS
2   KUMAR
```

Can anyone please help me the VBA or any excel function to remove duplicates from words?

Comment: What this have to do with R?

Comment: All data like same what you have posted here like `THOMASTHOMAS`, `KUMARKUMAR`, `XYZXYZ`, `PQRPQR`, `HarunHarun`?

Comment: What about names like "LEELEE" which is a valid name in its own right, as well as being two copies of "LEE"?

Answer (score 6):

If there is a mix of both duplicated and not duplicated then use this formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)/2)=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)/2),LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)/2),A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all cells have duplicated names, you can use this formula:

```
=LEFT(B1,LEN(B1)/2)
```